# How to make checkboxes work with knockout

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

I found this example from Ryan Niemeyer and started to manipulate it into the way I write my own code, but then it stopped working. Can anybody tell me why?

Alternative 1 is my variant
Alternative 2 is based upon Ryans solution and does work (just comment/uncomment the Applybindings).

Why doesn´t Alternative 1 work?

My issue is with the filteredRows:

```
self.filteredRows = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    //build a quick index from the flags array to avoid looping for each item
    var statusIndex = {};

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.flags(), function(flag) {
      statusIndex[flag] = true;
    }); 

    //return a filtered list
    var result = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.Textbatches(), function(text) {
        //check for a matching genré
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(text.genre(), function(genre) {
            return statusIndex[genre];
        });
        return false;
    });

    console.log("result", result);
    return result;

});
```

I want to filter my Textbatches on the genre-attribute (string in db and the data collected from the db is a string and not an array/object)

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gsey786h/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various problems, most of them can be simply fixed with checking your browser's JavaScript console and reading the exceptions...

So here is the list what you need to fix:

- You have miss-typed `Textbatches` in the declaration so the correct is `self.Textbatches = ko.observableArray();`
- You have scoping problem in `filteredRows` with the `this`. So if you are using `self` you should stick to it and use that:

  - `this.flags()` should be `self.flags()`
  - `this.Textbatches()` should be `self.Textbatches()`
- Your `genre` property has to be an array if you want to use it in `ko.utils.arrayFirst`
- Finally your `Textbatch` takes individual parameters but you are calling it with an object, so you need to change it to look like:

  ```
  Textbatch = function(data) {
      var self = this;
      self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
      self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
      self.statuses = ko.observableArray(data.status);
      self.genre = ko.observableArray(data.genre);
      self.createdBy = ko.observable(data.createdBy);  
  };
  ```

  or you can of course change the calling places to use individual arguments instead of an object.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ept6gkwq/) containing all the above mentioned fixes.

Comment: Thank, @nemesv. I was a bit hurried I think. (humble pie, himblepie) However my big issue (I guess) is that making Genre an array does´t fit my solution. So which alternatives do I have except the   "ko.utils.arrayFirst" ?

Comment: If you don't need an array for Genre just don't use an array and remove the `ko.utils.arrayFirst` and just return `statusIndex[text.genre()]` see in: http://jsfiddle.net/3zqndj8u/

Comment: So the  "return statusIndex[text.genre()]" returns true/false to the arrayFilter, and that´s what filtering the array, right?

Comment: yes if you return true from the `arrayFilter` that item will be included. You can read more about the KO array helpers here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html